# return value of sizeof

Tags: c, linux, sizeof

I have this XDR struct:

```
struct Response {
    bool_t error;
    float result;
};
typedef struct Response Response;
```

And in my main:

```
Response y;
y.result = 5.7; 
y.error = 0; 
fprintf(f,"y.error's size: %d bit\n",sizeof(y.error));
```

I obtain in my txt file:

```
y.error's size: 0 bit
```

MORE:

I have created an XDR struct (struct Response) with rpcgen. I send this struct to a client with a socket:

```
XDR xdrs_w;
Response y; 

FILE *stream_socket_w = fdopen(s, "w"); /* s is socket's file descriptor */
xdrstdio_create(&xdrs_w, stream_socket_w, XDR_ENCODE);

y.result = 6.8; 
y.error = 0; /* false */

if(!xdr_Response(&xdrs_w, &y)){
  printf("Error");
}

fflush(stream_socket_w);
```

The problem is with `xdr_Response` function. So I think that the mistake is in `y.error = 0`

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not bits, and I cannot [reproduce](http://ideone.com/Dl6paW) this. Can you post a [complete code file](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problematic behavior?

Comment: BTW: sizeof is **not** a function but a (unary) operator. It does not _return_ a value , but (applying it) evaluates to, or _yields_ a value. The type of what it evaluates to is a `size_t`, *not* an int.

Comment: You should use proper format specifier for printing `size_t` values. `%d` is not the right one. Use `%zu` or at least cast the `size_t` value to `int`. In any case, the result you posted is hard to believe. You need to provide more details. What is `bool_t`?

Comment: I have updated my question (for phihag)

Comment: What you posted is not directly relevant. And what do you mean by "mistake is in `y.error = 0`"? Nothing like that can affect the result of `sizeof`. XDR `bool_t` is an `int`, so its size is not zero. Also, what does "The problem is with `xdr_Response` function" mean? Are you doing your `printf` from inside `xdr_Response`? If not, then what problem are you talking about in this case?

Comment: You are right. Now I have see that bool_t is an int. The problem is that in the terminal I see the printf Error so I don't understand why. Help me please

Comment: Are you running on a big-endian machine (SPARC, PPC, ...)?  If so, what you're seeing is what is expected when you mismatch the type format `%d` with the value (`size_t`).  If `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(int)`, on a big-endian machine, you will print 0.  To get the right result, use C99 format `%zu`, or cast the value of `sizeof()` to an `int` to match the `%d` you use.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char bool_t;

struct Response {
  bool_t error;
  float result;
};
typedef struct Response Response;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Response r;

  r.result = 5.7;
  r.error = 0;

  printf("y.error's size: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(r.error));

  return 0;
}
```

Works for me as expected. bool_t is not standard type so I typedef'd it. Also remember, on 64bit platform sizeof() returns unsigned long, so you need to use %ld in your fprintf function.

Comment: `%ld` is not a proper format specifier for a `size_t`. Either cast to int and use `%d`, or cast to unsigned int and use `%u`, or format the size_t using the `%zu` specifier. (Note: `sizeof(size_t)` could be different from `sizeof(long int)` )

Comment: You're right, According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit (see sections 7.17 and 7.18.3). %zu is the correct specifier.

Comment: BTW: size_t was introduced in c89/c90. The `%zu` z format modifier was introduced in c99. And has always been unsigned.